# Dynamically create xml nodes

Tags: xml, groovy, nodes

I have a specific need where I'm parsing a file and then I need to create an xml file based upon the data that I've parsed.

For example, I've created two maps (tableMap, fieldMap).

```
tableMap: [1:{Table=patient}, 2:{Table=provider}]
fieldMap: [1:{Table=patient, Field=id}, 2:{Table=patient, Field=gender},  
   3:{Table=provider, Field=id}, 4:{Table=provider, Field=name}]
```

Using Groovy I will start with a loop through tableMap and get the first Table (patient).  Then I will loop through the fieldMap to get the fields that match the Table.

Below is some sample code that shows how I would like to dynamicly create node and element names with "value.Table(tag:'01',value.Field)":

```
tableMap.each
{ tKey, tValue ->

    // Find the Table value in the fieldMap that matches the value 
    // in the tableMap      
    def tableFields = fieldMap.findAll { fKey, fValue -> 
        fValue.Table == tValue.Table 
    }
    tValue.Table = []

    // Create an XML file with all the tables and field names collected.
    xsdToXml.root() 
    {

        // dynamically create xml nodes
        tableFields.each 
        { key, value ->
            value.Table + '()' {
                value.Table(tag:'01',value.Field)       
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I'm not sure if this is possible and if it isn't I'd just like someone to tell me so I don't waste anymore time on it.  If it is I would appreciate an example of how to do it.

Thanks - Karl

Comment: What should the xml look like?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Right, you don't say what you want the output XML to look like, but taking the fieldMap (you don't need the tableMap):

```
def fieldMap = [ 1:[ Table:'patient', Field:'id' ], 
                 2:[ Table:'patient', Field:'gender' ],  
                 3:[ Table:'provider', Field:'id' ],
                 4:[ Table:'provider', Field:'name' ] ]
```

You can do:

```
import groovy.xml.*

String x = new StreamingMarkupBuilder().bind {
    xml {
        fieldMap.values().groupBy { it.Table }.each { table, values ->
            "${table}" {
                values.each {
                    "${it.Field}"()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To generate the xml:

```
<xml>
    <patient>
        <id/>
        <gender/>
    </patient>
    <provider>
        <id/>
        <name/>
    </provider>
</xml>
```